# Routing based on REST method with Spring integration

Tags: spring-integration

I have several "int-http:inbound-gateway" and I need one of them to point at different services based on http method provided by the request.

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway path="....." supported-methods="POST,PUT"/>
```

At this moment I have 2 different endpoints and I was looking for some rest-method-based router but I have found nothing about this topic.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a header-value-router for this one as the http method is automatically set in the message header.

something like this

```
<int-http:inbound-channel-adapter channel="input.channel"
    path="/log" supported-methods="PUT,POST" request-payload-type="java.lang.String"/>

<int:channel id="input.channel"/>

<int:header-value-router input-channel="input.channel" header-name="#{T(org.springframework.integration.http.HttpHeaders).REQUEST_METHOD">
    <int:mapping value="PUT" channel="put.input.channel"/>
    <int:mapping value="POST" channel="post.input.channel"/>
</int:header-value-router>
```

hope that helps